# Perl, strings, floats, unit testing and regexps!

Tags: perl

OK, as a preface this question potentially is 'stupider' than my normal level of question - however this problem has been annoying me for the last few days so I'll ask it anyway. I'll give a mock example of what my problem is so I can hope to generalize it to my current problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w use strict;

use Test::More 'no_plan';

my $fruit_string = 'Apples cost $1.50';
my ($fruit, $price) = $fruit_string =~ /(\w+)s cost \$(\d+\.\d+)/;

# $price += 0; # Uncomment for Great Success
is ($price, 1.50, 'Great Success');
```

Now when this is run I get the message

```
#   Failed test 'Great Success'
#          got: '1.50'
#     expected: '1.5'
```

To make the test work - I either uncomment the commented line, or use `is ($price, '1.50', 'Great Success')`. Both options do not work for me - I'm testing a huge amount of nested data using Test::Deep and cmp_deeply. My question is, how can you extract a double from a regexp then use it immediately as a double - or if there is a better way altogether let me know - and feel free to tell me to take up gardening or something lol, learning Perl is hard.

Comment: You are comparing string with number, so they are compared as strings. I don't think you can do anything with it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're already using [Test::Deep,](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aDeep) so you can simply use the `num()` wrapper to perform a numerical rather than stringwise comparison (it even lets you add in a tolerance, for comparing two inexact floating point values):

```
cmp_deeply(
    $result,
    {
        foo         => 'foo',
        bar         => 'blah',
        quantity    => 3,
        price       => num(1.5),
    },
    'result hash is correct',
);
```

For normal comparisons done separately, `cmp_ok` will work, but `num()` is still available: `cmp_deeply($value, num(1.5), 'test name')` still works.

Answer (score 1):

Force `$price` to be interpreted as a number:

```
is ( 0 + $price, 1.50, 'Great Success');
```

Comment: @Platinum Azure: No, you really need to add the number.  Test it.

Comment: Yup, I looked at perlop again just to make sure and you're right. Maybe I'm thinking of Perl 6 or something.

Comment: As I stated in my post, I can't effectively use 0 + $price, since I'm using cmp_deeply - to do 0+$price, I would have to go through my entire current code and do it to every variable that should be a double.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the tried-and-true `ok`? You'll be testing the thing that you actually mean to test, and not have to worry about whether `is` is doing anything too subtle or too clever.

```
ok($price == 1.5, 'Great Success');
```

`is` does provide some additional diagnostics on failure, but that is easy enough to do with `ok`, too

```
ok($price == 1.5, 'Great Success') or diag("Expected \$price==1.5, got $price");
```

Comment: `is` supplies the expected and given values in case of a failed assertion, which `ok` cannot do.

Answer (score 1):

Your tests are failing because `is($x, $y, $name)` is equivalent to `cmp_ok($x, 'eq', $y, $name)`.  The `eq` forces each of its arguments to be evaluated as strings.  Since you want numeric equality, you could write it out with `cmp_ok` using `'=='`.  You could make things easier by writing your own numeric version of `is`:

```
sub is_num {cmp_ok $_[0], '==', $_[1], $_[2]}
```

But that version is subtly broken, it will report errors on the wrong lines.  To make sure that error reporting shows the right lines:

```
sub is_num {splice @_, 1, 0, '=='; goto &cmp_ok}
```

The reason for the `goto &sub` is because `cmp_ok` uses `caller` to determine where the error happened.  The `goto &sub` syntax erases the call frame setup for `is_num` so that `cmp_ok` thinks its being called from the location that `is_num` was.

Lastly, a plug of my module [Test::Magic](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aMagic) which provides syntactic sugar for `Test::More`:

```
use Test::Magic 'no_plan';

... # setup code

test 'fruit price',
  is $price == 1.50;
```

Which is interpreted as `cmp_ok( $price, '==', 1.50, 'fruit price')`

Comment: Instead of the `goto`, you should instead do `local $Test::Builder::Level = $Test::Builder::Level + 1;` to alter where the failing test is reported.

Comment: @Ether => why use an API specific solution when Perl provides a general purpose way to dispatch transparently?  There are a few situations where setting `$Test::Builder::Level` is needed (running multiple tests from one call site or performing post test actions), but this is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behavior is that is uses eq to do comparisons, which forces stringification of its arguments.  1.50 stringifies to '1.5' and this fails.

Your choices are to live with the behavior (force stringification or numification) or else write your own alternative to is which will compare numerically if both sides look like they are numbers before falling back on eq comparisons.  I would personally go with the latter approach.